# what's the meaning of tcpdump option vnn

Tags: tcpdump

Here is a tcpdump command:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 -vnn  udp
```

-i means interface
eth0 is the interface name
udp means upd protocol,
but,
What's this option[-vnn] meaning?

Comment: maybe `man tcpdump` can give you some hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'-vnn' is the same as specifying -v and -nn as two separate options. From the tcpdump manual:

> -v 
>        When parsing and printing, produce (slightly more) verbose output. For example, the time to live, identification, total length and options in an IP packet are printed. Also enables additional packet integrity checks such as verifying the IP and ICMP header checksum.
>
> -nn 
>        Don't convert protocol and port numbers etc. to names either.

Note that -nn implies -n as well.

Comment: This is what i want and make me clear. before ask this question, i type 'man tcpdump' in terminal,then show me the manual, i find -n, -v, options but not -vnn,eventually.so,I get it now, thx. very much.